# Why am I logged out of DataExlorer Exchange every day?

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

- When I log in to an SE site, that login generally persists (across days, and even across browser restarts).
- When I log in to ANOTHER SE site, that site will automatically log me in, based on my cross-se login.
- But when I go to [DataExplorer site](https://data.stackexchange.com/), where I logged in last time... only to discover I was logged out and have to MANUALLY re-login, once every couple of days or anytime I restart the browser.

Is there anyway I can get that site to have automated/preserved login the way normal SE sites do?